# Display chatter feed for multiple contacts in VF

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed-tracking

I have been tasked with replicating the Chatter tab for Contact List Views.  For any list view, I have to get the Feed Items for the last 30 days just like in the standard functionality.

What's frustrating is that there are some chatter components that come with styles "out of the box", like chatter:feed, chatter:feedWithFollowers, etc.  However, with these components, you have to specify an entityId, and I would need multiple entityIds (every Contact within the current ListView).

Is there really no other way to do this than getting a list of FeedItem objects in the controller where ParentId = ContactIds, then trying to replicate the complex Salesforce styles by outputting these in the Visualforce page?

Comment: How did you end up handling this? Did you replicate the HTML and hope it doesn't change it the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the standard `<chatter>` VF elements are limited to 1/page.

We've done something similar by using an `iFrame for each component`, this is really bad practice though.

I'd say you need to write custom APEX/VF to query all the feeds and display them instead of using the VF components.

Comment: How would you replicate the styling of the feed? Would you have to actually copy the HTML a normal chatter feed renders?

Comment: it's very very complicated...the - you essentially have to copy the HTML and styling yes. it was horrible and they change it without warning.